# Trying to get a REPEAT UNTIL (DO...WHILE) loop working in C

Tags: c

So I am writing this code for simple shape determining program, and I was trying to loop it, the condition, for the loop to end is when the value of the variable x is equal to 0 (all of teh variables are angels), since an angle cannot be 0, I think it is only logical to have the loop loop until the value entered is 0. However, the code does not seem to stop iterating even after the condition is met. the code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    int A=0;
    do {
    printf("What is the value of x?");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("What is the value of y?");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    printf("What is the value of A?");
    scanf("%d", &A);
    if ((A==90)&&(x==y))
        {
            printf("Square\n");
        }
    else if ((A==90)&&(x!=y))
        {
            printf("Rectangle\n");
        }
     else if ((A==60)||(A==120))
        {
            printf("Hexagonal\n");
        }
     else if ((A!=60)||(A!=120)&&(x==y))
        {
            printf("Rhombic\n");
        }
     else if ((A!=60)||(A!=120)&&(x!=y))
        {
            printf("Parallelogram\n");
        }
    else
    {
        printf("The values you have entered are not supported by the program, 
try again!");

    }
    }while(x!=0);
    printf("Thanks for using the program!");



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I cannot really see what the problem with the condition for the while loop is, please help!

Comment: learn to use your debugger

Comment: i assume A is the angle. but you are testing x in the while condition

Comment: Works for me, terminates when I enter `0` (for x).

Comment: Basically all of the inputs are angles, and since x is the first variable therefore  I am trying to make it that when the input for x is 0 the loop should end

Comment: @Benny you can check if any of the variables are 0 by using

while(x!=0 && y != 0 && A != 0)

Comment: It works only the first time, but if you enter 0 again it doesn't work

Comment: @Benny "*when the input for x is 0 the loop should end*" <- do you mean: *immediately*? The condition is checked at the end of your loop, just like you write it in your code! It works as designed...

Comment: It kinda works, but how do you get the program to end staright after the input of x, the program should not ask for the inputs for y and A

Comment: @FelixPalmen i mean immediately

Comment: well, then check directly after your `scanf()` and `break` the loop... You can then use an "infinite" loop instead (`for (;;)` or `while (1)`, they're equivalent).

Comment: what do you mean by break?

Comment: the statement `break`. Maybe you should read a book on C?

Comment: I understand, but how would i implement that in my code?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way may be:

```
    scanf("%d", &x);
    if (!x) break;        // break the loop, not asking anything else
```